# my GRU performs not so good like basic machine learning approach, why

Tags: r, keras, time-series

I´m using rainfall data to predict something (using keras sequential in R). I´ve tried basic machine learning approach and a GRU model. But it truns out that the basic approach works much better than the GRU model. So my question is, is it normal? Or it means I´ve done something wrong.

And here is the basic model:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
 layer_flatten(input_shape = c(lookback / step, dim(data)[-1])) %>% 
 layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>% 
 layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

Here is the GRU model:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
 layer_gru(units = 64, input_shape = list(NULL, dim(data)[[-1]])) %>% 
 layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

Is GRU a better model for timeseries things? Can I use the basic approach with lookback for timeseries things?
Thanks!